# clear window Javascript Slideshow

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a slidshow in javascript and got this far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showPic1(){
document.write("<img src=\"http://haga.mizgalski.se/upload/upload/bild1.jpg\" width=\"400\" height=\"300\">");
setTimeout(showPic2, 5000);
}

function showPic2(){
document.write("<img src=\"http://haga.mizgalski.se/upload/upload/image2.jpg\" width=\"400\" height=\"300\">");
setTimeout(showPic1, 9000);
}
showPic1();
</script>
```

But my problem is when it should change picture, it just adds a new picture next to the first one. How to clear the window?

Comment: You should use `position: absolute;` on images within a container with `position: relative;` and change the `z-index` of the element you want to display on the top.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/QU2bX/

---

```
<head>
<style>
body {
    padding: 5px;
    border-left: 2px dotted brown;
    text-align: center;
}
img,input,div {
    margin: 0;
}
img {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(20,20,20,0.5);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x200" id="pic"/>
    <hr/>
    <input type="button" value="Start" onclick="init();"/>
    <input type="button" value="Stop" onclick="abort();"/>
    <script>
    var l = 6;
    var pictures = new Array(l);
    var c = 0;
    var img = document.querySelector('#pic');

    for(var i=0;i<l;i++) {
        pictures[i] = 'http://placehold.it/350x' + parseInt(Math.random() * 100);
    }

    console.log(pictures);

    img.src= pictures[c];

    function animate() {
        img.src= pictures[c];
        if(c == l-1) {c = -1;}
        c += 1;
    }

    function init() {
        window.timer = setInterval(animate,1000);
    }
    function abort() {
        if(window.timer) {clearInterval(timer);}
    }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: but how to have different time on each picture?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to give your `<img>` tags IDs, and then remove them from the DOM before inserting the new one:

```
function showPic1(){
var oldpic = document.getElementById("pic2");
oldpic.parentNode.removeChild(oldpic);
document.write("<img src=\"http://haga.mizgalski.se/upload/upload/bild1.jpg\" width=\"400\" height=\"300\" id=\"pic1\">");
setTimeout(showPic2, 5000);
}

function showPic2(){
var oldpic = document.getElementById("pic1");
oldpic.parentNode.removeChild(oldpic);
document.write("<img src=\"http://haga.mizgalski.se/upload/upload/image2.jpg\" width=\"400\" height=\"300\" id=\"pic2\">");
setTimeout(showPic1, 9000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating new images for the slideshow, use a single `img` tag and replace it's `src` attribute with a new image every so often.  For this you could use Javascript's `setTimeout()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Using document.write is a bad idea because it overwrites any code on the page.  It's a better idea to have a div with an id, and alter the html for the div through javascript.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
function showPic1(){
$('#test').html("<img src='http://haga.mizgalski.se/upload/upload/bild1.jpg' width='400' height='300'>");
setTimeout(showPic2, 5000);
}

function showPic2(){
$('#test').html("<img src='http://haga.mizgalski.se/upload/upload/image2.jpg' width='400' height='300'>");
setTimeout(showPic1, 9000);
}
showPic1();
</script>
<div id="test"><img src='http://haga.mizgalski.se/upload/upload/bild1.jpg' width='400' height='300'></div>
```

Something like that works well.